# How can I avoid extra copying when constructing a vector to be returned?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, push-back

C++ newbie here! I wrote a code who is considering a `WORLD` which made of a vector of `CITIES`. This world gets updated `nbTimeStep` times. Here is a rough summary of what my code looks like. For ease of reading, all class names are in all caps.

```
// Definition of Class `WORLD`
class WORLD
{
  private:
    vector<CITY> cities;
  public:
    void AddCity(CITY& city)
    {
      cities.push_back(city);
    }
}

// In main

WORLD world(Arguments);
for (int time_step=0 ; time_step < nbTimeSteps ; time_step++)
{
   WORLD EmptyWorld;
   world = ReCreateWorld(world,EmptyWorld); // The object `EmptyWorld` will be returned after being 'filled' with cities.
}
```

where the function `ReCreateWorld` is defined as

```
WORLD& ReCreateWorld(WORLD& OldWorld, WORLD& NewWorld)
{
  for (int city_index=0 ; city_index < NbCities ; city_index++)
  {
    /* Long Process of creating a single 'CITY' called `city`
    ...
    ...
    */


    // Add the city to the list of cities (process I am trying to optimize)
    NewWorld.AddCity(city);
  }
    return NewWorld;
}
```

After profiling, I see that about 20% of the time the process is in the method `AddCity`. I never need two instances of any given `CITY`, so it seems silly to lose so much time copying each city. **How could I go around this issue?**

---

Some may want to comment on the fact that I pass an empty `WORLD` to `ReCreateCities` as it is not very elegant. I did that mainly to emphasize that the slow copying part happen at the line `cities.push_back(city);` and not when `ReCreateWorld` return its `WORLD`.

Comment: An answer depends somewhat on what `CITY` looks like. Can it be moved (does it have a move constructor)?

Comment: If you're unsure what a move constructor is, `CITY`'s move constructor would be a constructor declared as `CITY(CITY&&);`, with two ampersands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Justin and Daniel suggested, use a move c-tor. Old school way is to use pointers, e.g.
        typedef std::unique_ptr CITY_PTR;
        std::vector cities;
And push only pointers of cities.

You can try something similar to `emplace` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/ which forwards c-tor arguments directly.

Comment: Thank you. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572669/move-with-vectorpush-back) was very helpful as well.